# Setting separate choices for argument with two values using argparse in Python

Tags: python, argparse

I currently have the following code:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Adds a new modem to Iridium account')
parser.add_argument('imei', metavar='I', nargs=1, help='the modems IMEI')
parser.add_argument('-t1', '--type1', metavar='t1', nargs=1, choices=('email', 'directip', 'sbddevice'), default='directip', help='Call type (default: directip)')
parser.add_argument('-a1', '--address1', metavar='a1', nargs=1, default='75.101.138.217:9097', help='Call address (default: 75.101.138.217:9097)')
parser.add_argument('-t2', '--type2', metavar='t2', nargs=1, choices=('email', 'directip', 'sbddevice'), help='Call type')
parser.add_argument('-a2', '--address2', metavar='a2', nargs=1, help='Call address')
parser.add_argument('-t3', '--type3', metavar='t3', nargs=1, choices=('email', 'directip', 'sbddevice'), help='Call type')
parser.add_argument('-a3', '--address3', metavar='a3', nargs=1, help='Call address')
parser.add_argument('-t4', '--type4', metavar='t4', nargs=1, choices=('email', 'directip', 'sbddevice'), help='Call type')
parser.add_argument('-a4', '--address4', metavar='a4', nargs=1, help='Call address')
parser.add_argument('-t5', '--type5', metavar='t5', nargs=1, choices=('email', 'directip', 'sbddevice'), help='Call type')
parser.add_argument('-a5', '--address5', metavar='a5', nargs=1, help='Call address')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

Is there a way I can combine all the -t and -a into say -m1, -m2, -m3, -m4, -m5 where t is the first value of the argument which the same choices below and -a is the second argument but not restricted to the same choices as the first value? It seems like you should be able to do this otherwise you have to do a bunch of checking later on to see if there is a t1 and a1 since if the user provides one they need to provide the other.

So instead of doing `-t1 email -a1 test@email.com` you could just do `-m1 email test@gmail.com`

Comment: What about a simpler `-m1 email:test@gmail.com` instead?  I don't yet know `argparse` well enough to tell how easy it is (if feasible) to make it gobble two args for one option, but as a user I'd be astonished at such weird parsing behavior, while `type:wh@tever` feels perfectly natural to me.

Comment: Also the restriction to exact five addresses looks a bit arbitrary. Maybe you just want the addresses as positional arguments and the IMEI as option?

Comment: You can have it accept two args with `nargs=2` and parse the output after that (Your `choices=` won't work with that though). But I guess you went with the `~` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this will help anyone down the road, but I ended up doing what Alex suggested. Only thing is I used `~` instead of `:` because I had to handle IP addresses with ports so using `:` would screw things up.

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but I'm learning about this myself, and thought I'd post an answer. The `nargs` parameter can take care of this, but obviously cannot be combined with `choices`, since it would apply to the email address as well:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(
    description='Adds a new modem to Iridium account',
    formatter_class=argparse.ArgumentDefaultsHelpFormatter
)
parser.add_argument('imei', metavar='I', help="the modem's IMEI")
parser.add_argument('-m1', nargs=2, metavar=("type","address"), default=['directip', '75.101.138.217:9097'], help='Call setting')
parser.add_argument('-m2', nargs=2, metavar=("type","address"), help='Call setting')
parser.add_argument('-m3', nargs=2, metavar=("type","address"), help='Call setting')
parser.add_argument('-m4', nargs=2, metavar=("type","address"), help='Call setting')
parser.add_argument('-m5', nargs=2, metavar=("type","address"), help='Call setting')

args = parser.parse_args()

type1 = args.multi1[0]
address1 = args.multi1[1]
if not type1 in ['email', 'directip', 'sbddevice']:
    args.print_help()
    sys.exit(1)
...
```